# How do I make an event occur on 5 clicks of an image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, increment

I have tried to make it work but it just doesn't. I'm trying to change the background image on 5 clicks, but even putting a simple alert in the else statement of my function doesn't trigger it.

```
<img  src="images\Wheel1.png" id="Wheel1" onclick="changeImage();lights();" />

<script>

function lights() { 

     var count = 0;
    
      if (count < 5) {
        count++;
      } else {
        document.body.background = "images/BackgroundLight.jpg";
      }
    
}
```

Comment: You have forgotten to close the script tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to declare the variable outside the function :

```
var count = 0;

function lights() {
  if (count < 5) {
    count++;
  } else {
    document.body.background = "images/BackgroundLight.jpg"
  }
}
```